# Reusing (re-opening) Oracle refcursor

Tags: oracle, sys-refcursor

I have two Oracle refcursors one containing list of Rows(CustomersList) and the other containing column names(PriceGroups) of each Row.
I need to loop through each Row and column and update the intersection of each Row/Column.
How can I re-position columns cursor to begin on the first column again and again.
The table looks following

```
Customer   | pricegroupA | priceGroupB | priceGroupC | priceGroupEtc|
-----------+---------------------------------------------------------
aaaa       | 23.5        | 23.8        | 30.9        | 41.3         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
bbbb       | 21.7        | 24.6        | 49.9        | 45.9         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
....
```

Comment: dursun answered the question one way.  By re-using  did you mean cursor sharing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you had shared a bunch of code I could rewrite it for you, but i think the following example will be helpful for you.

```
declare
  type r_cursor is REF CURSOR;
  c_emp r_cursor;
  en emp.ename%type;
begin
   /*Opening the refCursor for the first time*/
   open c_emp for select ename from emp;
  loop
      fetch c_emp into en;
      exit when c_emp%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line(en);
  end loop;
  /*Closing it*/  
  close c_emp;
 /*Opening the refCursor again after it is closed*/
  open c_emp for select ename from emp;
  loop
      fetch c_emp into en;
      exit when c_emp%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line(en);
  end loop;
  close c_emp;
  /*Closing it again*/  
end;
```